# Python module installation problem with Flask-WTF

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, flask-wtforms

(Merge this question, if necessary)

I am building a basic Flask-based app within a virtual environment and activated the virtual env. Installed each module correctly including this one. In the process, I have made a primary Py file alongside a file to direct all routes and another one for form. I properly installed the module within the environment and even updated it multiple times.

Whenever I am trying to run it (via Git Bash), it is throwing some scripting error and shows the unavailability of the module Flask-wtf. I could not gather any idea. The error is being occurred for all Py files
Inserting ***only the necessary codes*** of each Py file:

***Main application file****

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'aaa - key' #key to generate CSRF token
from route import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run (debug=True)
```

****Route file****:

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template

import forms

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/page1')
def page1():
    return render_template ('page1.html',
    current_title='Head 1')

@app.route('/page2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page2():
    form = forms.AddTaskForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('Submitted',form.title.data)
        return render_template('page2.html', form=form, title=form.title.data)
    return render_template ('page2.html', form=form)
```

3. Forms

   from wsgiref.validate import validator
   from flask_wtf import Form, FlaskForm
   from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
   from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

   class AddTaskForm(FlaskForm):
   title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
   submit = SubmitField('Send')

***Error***:

```
   app.py", line 6, in <module>
   route.py", line 7, in <module>
    forms.py", line 2, in <module>

    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf'
```

Comment: Can you run forms.py correctly？

Comment: Yes. I installed the package within Git Bash.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? I think this is a strange question. Looking at the error report, it is obvious that there is a problem when importing this file, but there is no problem when running it alone.

Comment: The very blunt error report also baffled me. However, I said 'Yes', against your question before this one. It couldn't run it as I did not install it within the Bash environment. After I did execute so, it ran.

Comment: So the current situation is still that `forms.py` can run normally independently, but will an error be reported after being imported? Have you ever tried to run in a new environment

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. I imported it from Bash (or any emulating environment. I have a very limited idea about others) which made it run well and I could, least to say, used it for the app. It sufficed the problem when Bash-based import happened. However, there's a new validator issue raised which I am trying to solve now.
No, I did not try it in a new environment.

Answer (score 1):

instead try with:

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
class AddTaskForm(Form): 
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()]) 
    submit = SubmitField('Send')
```

Answer (score 0):

install the module

```
pip install flask-wtf
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing the flask-wtf package in my machine as well instead of just in the venv. I opened a new terminal window and ran:

> pip install flask-wtf

Then I deactivated the virtual environment, reactivated, and reran the flask server. It ran fine after that.

Note that I reran the server before and I still got the same problem:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf'